# Hive Data isnt being updated

Tags: database, flutter, hive

this is my function to initialize Hive and put some dummy data inside it if its empty , the but the data doesnt gets displayed  , what i figured out is that its not even getting called on the hot restarts or reloads not even when i close the app the rebuild it , the only time the when i can see the updated values of the dummyDietPlan is when i uninstall the app and build it again , why is the _initializeHive() is only getting called once in the life time of the app ?
other than this issue , everything else working fine with hive , but just cant figure out why this issue is coming up

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeHive();
    _checkDietIsViewed();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeHive() async {
    if (!isInitialized) {
      await HiveService.initHive();
      setState(() {
        isInitialized = true;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _initializeDummyData() async {
    final dietPlans = await HiveService.retrieveDietPlan();
    if (dietPlans.isEmpty) {
      final dummyDietPlan = DietPlan( ... // dummy diet plan inserted
      await HiveService.UpdateDietPlan(dummyDietPlan);
      await HiveService.printDietPlans();
    }
  }
  
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<DietPlan>>(
        future: HiveService.retrieveDietPlan(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
            // Call _initializeHiveAndData() here to handle empty data
           _initializeHive();
            return Text('No diet plans available.');
          } else {
            final dietPlans = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView.builder(
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[this is before reinstallation , just a hot restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDsVv.png)

[This is after reinstallation of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6zER.png)

i was expecting that when i change the values of the dummy diet plan the it will reflect on my diet page but it does not

Answer (score 0):

you got this issue because you are calling _initializeHive  method in FutureBuilder in you Build method,

so, you have to move _initializeHive  and _initializeDummyData to initState method.

and in initState method, call _initializeDummyData after Hive has been initialized,

here is correct code -

```
class YourPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YourPageState createState() => _YourPageState();
}

class _YourPageState extends State<YourPage> {
  bool isInitialized = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeHiveAndData();
    _checkDietIsViewed();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeHiveAndData() async {
    if (!isInitialized) {
      await HiveService.initHive();
      await _initializeDummyData();
      setState(() {
        isInitialized = true;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _initializeDummyData() async {
    final dietPlans = await HiveService.retrieveDietPlan();
    if (dietPlans.isEmpty) {
      final dummyDietPlan = DietPlan(...); // dummy diet plan inserted
      await HiveService.UpdateDietPlan(dummyDietPlan);
      await HiveService.printDietPlans();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<DietPlan>>(
        future: HiveService.retrieveDietPlan(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
            return Text('No diet plans available.');
          } else {
            final dietPlans = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: dietPlans.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                // Build your list item here
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```